# Does gspread Support Accessing Spreadsheets on Team Drives?

Tags: python, google-apps-script, gspread

I am trying to access a Spreadsheet on a Team Drive using gspread. It is not working.  It works if the spreadsheet is on my Google Drive. I was wondering if gspread has the new Google Drive API v3 capability available to open spreadsheets on Team Drives. If so, how do I specify the fact I want to open a spreadsheet on a Google Team Drive and not my own Google drive? If not, when will that functionality be available? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-teamdrives). Be noted that with items in *My Drive*, each user is granted access with a specific role. An additional role, `organizer`, has been added for Team Drives. The `organizer` role is required to to modify the location of files in a Team Drive and remove content. The `owner` role is not allowed in Team Drives.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the latest version of gspread. The one that is e.g. bundled with Google Colab is outdated:

`!pip install --upgrade gspread`

This fixed the error in `gs.csv_import` for me on a team drive.